# DISTINCT after ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

I'm basically creating a forum. I'm outputting all the topics with my 'posts' and 'members' table joined with it. This way I can display post and member info on the topic index.

What I'm trying to do is collect the username of the last three members who posted, I only want unique values (no duplicates in case someone double posts) I'm currently using DISTINCT, but the trouble is that the usernames are grouped after they're ordered backwards. If someone did the first and last post, I won't be able to retrieve their username among this list.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `members`.`username` ORDER BY `posts`.`date` DESC SEPARATOR '\\\\') , '\\\\', 3
) AS member_last_username
```

Is there a way I could modify that code so that the usernames are ordered backwards before their grouping? I apologize if my question is confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, do a subselect that orders your data the way you want and use that as input.

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sub.username ORDER BY sub.`date` 
                 DESC SEPARATOR '\\\\') , '\\\\', 3
  ) AS member_last_username
FROM (SELECT m.username, p.`date` 
      FROM members m
      INNER JOIN post p ON (some join or other)
      ORDER BY backwards ordering ) sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a great help. I was focusing so much on the SELECT, I completely forgot about subselecting.